# How to add a title to each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, subtitle

I have one figure which contains many subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(26, 12), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Window Title')

# Returns the Axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(311) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312) 
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
```

How do I add titles to the subplots?

`fig.suptitle` adds a title to all graphs and although `ax.set_title()` exists, the latter does not add any title to my subplots.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
Corrected typo about `set_title()`. Thanks Rutger Kassies

Answer (score 513, accepted):

`ax.title.set_text('My Plot Title')` seems to work too.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax1.title.set_text('First Plot')
ax2.title.set_text('Second Plot')
ax3.title.set_text('Third Plot')
ax4.title.set_text('Fourth Plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib add titles on subplots]

Comment: For anyone having problems with the font size for a histogram, oddly enough reducing the number of bins let me increase it.  Went from 500 to 100.

Comment: If you need to be able to specify the fontsize, use `ax.set_title('title', fontsize=16)` instead.

Comment: @TobiasP.G., how do you position the title inside the subplot?

Comment: Hi @Jarad, thank you for your answer. At that time, I used ```ax2.text()``` because ```ax2.title.set_y()``` wasn't somehow working. Given 4 subplots of the same size, if I gave a value of $0.9$ for $y$ to each subplot's ```axis.title.set_y()```, it still  put the titles at weird locations and didn't match for each subplot.

Answer (score 332):

`ax.set_title()` should set the titles for separate subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Title for whole figure", fontsize=16)
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax.set_title("Title for first plot")
ax.plot(data)

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax.set_title("Title for second plot")
ax.plot(data)

plt.show()
```

Can you check if this code works for you? Maybe something overwrites them later?

Comment: This works for me, matplotlib version 1.2.2 python 2.7.5

Comment: On matplotlib 3.5.2 this throws a ValueError on plt.subplot("211") / plt.subplot("212") . The solution is to just replace with integer arguments, plt.subplot(211) & plt.subplot(212).

Answer (score 64):

A shorthand answer assuming 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`:

```
plt.gca().set_title('title')
```

as in:

```
plt.subplot(221)
plt.gca().set_title('title')
plt.subplot(222)
etc...
```

Then there is no need for superfluous variables.

Comment: this approach is nice because it gives more control over the title position...e.g. by adding kwarg y=0.7 you can plot the subplot title within the subplot

Answer (score 18):

If you want to make it shorter, you could write :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1).set_title(f'Subplot n°{i+1}')
plt.show()
```

It makes it maybe less clear but you don't need more lines or variables

Answer (score 14):

A solution I tend to use more and more is this one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)  # 1
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()): # 2
    ax.set_title("Plot #{}".format(i)) # 3
```

1. Create your arbitrary number of axes
2. axs.ravel() converts your 2-dim object to a 1-dim vector in row-major style
3. assigns the title to the current axis-object

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, the requested result can also be achieve without explicit reference to the figure axes as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(221)
plt.title("Title 1")

plt.subplot(222)
plt.title("Title 2")

plt.subplot(223)
plt.title("Title 3")

plt.subplot(224)
plt.title("Title 4")
```

[image]

Use `plt.tight_layout()` after the last plot if you have issues with overlapping labels.

Answer (score 6):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4,figsize=(11, 7))

grid = plt.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.5)

ax1 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(grid[0, 1:])
ax3 = plt.subplot(grid[1, :1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(grid[1, 1:])

ax1.title.set_text('First Plot')
ax2.title.set_text('Second Plot')
ax3.title.set_text('Third Plot')
ax4.title.set_text('Fourth Plot')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how to add space between subplots and their titles.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have multiple images and you want to loop though them and show them 1 by 1 along with titles - this is what you can do. No need to explicitly define ax1, ax2, etc.

1. The catch is you can define dynamic axes(ax) as in Line 1 of code
   and you can set its title inside a loop.
2. The rows of 2D array is length (len) of axis(ax)
3. Each row has 2 items i.e. It is list within a list (Point No.2)
4. set_title can be used to set title, once the proper axes(ax) or subplot is selected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 8))  
for i in range(len(ax)): 
    for j in range(len(ax[i])):
        ## ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_gr[0].reshape(28,28))
        ax[i,j].set_title('Title-' + str(i) + str(j))
```

Answer (score 4):

You are able to give every graph a different title and label by Iteration only.

```
titles = {221: 'First Plot', 222: 'Second Plot', 223: 'Third Plot', 224: 'Fourth Plot'}
fig = plt.figure()
for x in range(221,225):
  ax = fig.add_subplot(x)
  ax.title.set_text(titles.get(x))

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,
                    bottom=0.1, 
                    right=0.9, 
                    top=0.9, 
                    wspace=0.4, 
                    hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the `subplots_adjust` call cures overlapping titles. So this is very useful. Thank you!

Comment: How to add some space between the subplot's title and its plot. For eg. vertical space between the heading First plot and its corressponding plot

Answer (score 4):

As of matplotlib 3.4.3, the [Figure.add_subplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) function supports kwargs with title as:

```
fig.add_subplot(311, title="first")
fig.add_subplot(312, title="second")
```

Comment: Simple and works perfectly (don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes)