# How do you add an overall title to a figure with subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can see that you can add a title to each subplot, as discussed here:

[How to add title to subplots in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239933/how-to-add-title-to-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Is there a way to add an overall title *in addition* to the subplot titles?

[image: overall title]

Comment: Looks like it is... the title of that question is not very informative though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('this is the figure title')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title('overall')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax1.title.set_text('First Plot')
ax2.title.set_text('Second Plot')
ax3.title.set_text('Third Plot')
ax4.title.set_text('Fourth Plot')
plt.show()
```

everything but the second line is copied from the link you posted.

Tested with python 2.7