# Title on graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making plots in a loop:

```
plotData.sort_values(by=['segment'])
for date in plotData.month_of_default.unique():
    plt.figure()
    temp =plotData[plotData.month_of_default==date][['New_Amount_2','ID','segment','total','payment','month']]
    denom = temp.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).groupby('segment')['total'].sum()

    test = temp.groupby(['segment','month']).New_Amount_2.sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum()/denom

    
plt.plot(test.unstack().T)
```

I've tried putting title='' in the plt.plot() brackets and in plt.figure(), also adding fig.subtitle('Title', fontsize=16) and neither worked - what's the right syntax to do this? Thanks! :)

Comment: I think the function you want to use is `plt.title()`. You can add that anywhere below `plt.figure()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a title to each subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239933/how-to-add-a-title-to-each-subplot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a title to each subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239933/how-to-add-a-title-to-each-subplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a title to in matplotlib is done via the `FigureBase` object which would be returned by `plt.figure()` in your example. See these docs for more info: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html

In your example this would look like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("your plot title")
```

However if you're making multiple plots, using `plt.subplots()` to get access directly to the figure and axes objects would give you more direct control over their appearance. See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html